# How to automatically fill range by interpolating between lower and upper bounds

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I apologize I do not have any code or examples too show for this. I am not sure how to even approach or identify the function or result I would like to achieve.

What I have is spreadsheet with recorded data times and events. I will need to chart this to look for correlation against other data, so I will need all points to have complete data sets. When the data was recorded it has some empty fields. So I am looking to a way to generate a range to complete the empty fields.

```
1240    missing bottle
110     missing bottle
140     missing bottle
1145    bottles fell out
        hungup
        bottles fell out
        bottles fell out
        bottles fell out
        bottles fell out
        bottles fell out
1520    bottles fell out
1550    bottles fell out
1615    up
1645    bottles fell out
1715    up
```

So I would like to just balance the values in between 1145 and 1520, in a automated way. Since there is 6 spaced between them with a difference of `375/6 = 62.5`. Is there a way to to do this automatically?

Comment: You want column A missing values to be interpolated based on the adjacent values and spread evenly?

Comment: Yes,  [interpolated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) - TIL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Highlight the first and last values along with the blank cells, this is your range.

Now you can go to the ribbon at **Home - Editing - Fill** and select **series...** It should predict your step value for you:

[image]

results:

[image]

Or, you can do the same and specify your own step value.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it either replaces every value with `1` or replaces the existing values with its own trending values (using `Trend`).

Comment: @PeterX sounds like a formatting issue

Comment: No, it's simply because Excel can't handle intermediate ("between") values

Comment: OMG, how did I not know this - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting all cells in the column including the top and bottom, just select the range where the gap is, but also include just one already filled in cell above and one below the range and follow the steps from the previous answer. Check the box for trend. Then it will autofill without changing your already completed data.