# How to automatically fill range in excel by interpolating between lower and upper bounds

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-auto-fill

I want to interpolate between A00-B99 and have excel expand the series to A00, A01, A02,.... all the way to B99.

SO if I have A00 in one cell and want to have excel automatically fill down to B99, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1506789/edit) to clarify it

Answer (score 2):

in the first cell put:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

or just put the first value:

[image]

Then referring to that cell and the cell with the range use:

```
=IF(OR(C1=RIGHT($A$1,3),C1=""),"",IF(RIGHT(C1,2)+1=100,CHAR(CODE(LEFT(C1))+1)&"00",LEFT(C1)&TEXT(RIGHT(C1,2)+1,"00")))
```

And copy down the column.

[image]

Note:  This is not a silver bullet.  It is based on there being one Letter and two numbers in the setup.  Any other combination and this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()<101,"A"&TEXT(ROW()-1,"00"),"B"&TEXT(ROW()-101,"00"))
```

and copy downwards

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of a column (or wherever you want to start the sequence) and fill down.

```
=TEXT(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 100), "\"&CHAR(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/100)+65)&"00")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is all ready a forum post relating to your post.
You can check it out here: [How to automatically fill range by interpolating between lower and upper bounds](https://superuser.com/questions/902900/how-to-automatically-fill-range-by-interpolating-between-lower-and-upper-bounds)

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I have characters and numbers mixed together